# How to create Full Page Scroll in Vanilla Javascript. No Libraries

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

This code is working fine on firefox, chrome ( But not working on mobiles and also on mac operating system. I tried everything but not working. Please help me to find a solution. I'm stuck on it.
This code is working fine on firefox, chrome ( But not working on mobiles and also on mac operating system. I tried everything but not working. Please help me to find a solution. I'm stuck on it.

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.fullscreensection');

const animationDuration = 1000;
let lastTime = 0;

let index = 0;

// Scroll to next Section
function moveNext() {

    if (index > sections.length - 2) {

        return;
    }
    index++;

    sections.forEach((section, i) => {

        if (i === index) {
            section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
        }
        console.log("This");

    })

    console.log(index);

}

// Scroll to next Section
function movePrev() {

    if (index < 1) {

        return;
    }
    index--;

    sections.forEach((section, i) => {

            if (i === index) {
                section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
            }
            // console.log("This");

        })
        // console.log(index);

}


window.addEventListener("wheel", e => {


    const value = e.deltaY;
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    console.log(value);

    if (currentTime - lastTime < animationDuration) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if (value < 0) {
        moveNext();
    } else {

        movePrev();
    }

    lastTime = currentTime;

}, { passive: false })

// /============================== Full Page Scrooling Sections
```

Comment: Phone usually does not have a scroll wheel. Use `scroll`.

Comment: @ChloeAnderson I tried using scroll also but not working for me. I just want fullpage.js like functionality in vanilla javascript

Comment: Why would you want to create it from the scratch? Re-inventing the wheel is not usually a good idea unless your whole purpose is learning JavaScript. There are sooooo many edge cases you are not considering and a library like fullPage.js has been out for about 7 years and proven to do a good job.

Comment: I know it's not good to build this from scratch but my client ( Upwork ) wants this functionality in vanilla javascript.